# Eclipse giving expected identifier error on seemingly proper code

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

So, I've been attempting to get eclipse set up for writing C for a comp sci course, however, I immediately get the error reading "Expected Identifier or '(' before '{'" on all code I write, but it is calling the error at the brace after establishing main. This is completely preventing me from building or running any programs through Eclipse.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello Eclipse\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: 1) Possible non-printing character lurking someplace.  2) Watch out for _smart quotes_ 3) Phase of the moon ....

Comment: Unless you post a hex dump of the source code which may reveal the offending byte, the posted code looks OK and so the problem is not replicable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I had not realized why it is called Eclipse until now! This explains everything!